# How can I change the value of a variable embedded within a function?

Tags: javascript

I am using a pop-up calendar javascript function which is used across our application. I have a page that uses the pop-up within a Bootstrap modal.

Currently, if the user has to scroll down the page, then open a modal, then click on the button to invoke the calendar pop-up, the pop-up calendar "appears" above the scroll (ie: if you kept the modal open and scrolled all the way up, the calendar would line up perfectly).

I have hacked a fix by declaring an additional click event for the button that invokes the calendar widget ( `$('#show_cal').click( function(){ $('div.calendar').css('position', 'fixed'); } );` ). I'd rather manipulate the base Calendar setup to have the calendar div come in styled as `position:fixed`.

So, given the following JavaScript snippet (there's more to the function, but it's likely not relevant), how can I redefine `s.position` to be "fixed" (instead of "absolute")?

```
    Calendar.prototype.showAtElement = function (el, opts) {
            function fixPosition(box) {
                    var cp = document.createElement("div");
                    var s = cp.style;
                    s.position = "absolute";
            };
    };
```

Comment: I assume you are looking for an other answer than *"replace that line with `s.position = "fixed";`"*? Please provide a better explanation of your problem.

Comment: I don't get it, change what how exactly, it's not really a variable, it's a style?

Comment: what's exactly your problem ?

Comment: Something tells me this code is wrong; you're neither returning nor calling the inner function `fixPosition`.

Comment: Sorry guys, I omitted detail in the interest of brevity. Added some detail...

Comment: There is nothing you can do programmatically. You could overwrite the function with your own implementation. The better approach would probably be to refactor the code so that it accepts the position value as argument somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it if you don't have access to the code Calendar is defined in so you can replace the value is to override the function with a new one that does what you want. Add the following AFTER Calendar was defined, but before you use the showAtElement method:

```
Calendar.prototype.showAtElement = function (el, opts) {
        function fixPosition(box) {
                var cp = document.createElement("div");
                var s = cp.style;
                s.position = "fixed";
        };
};
```